# How to build a nested IF statement in SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement

I have an issue where I want use certain query in certain case, but can not get the syntax to work. I am guessing it is because of the multiple IF´s but could someone enlighten me please how to fix it?

```
    IF smthn = 1 THEN
     SELECT stuff ,
      IFNULL(t3.value3,0.00) av_value,
       IF (t1.value1= t2.value2, t1.value1+ IFNULL(t3.value3,0.00) , t1.value1) kumul ,)
    t2.value2 summa
    FROM tbl_1 t1

    END//
        END IF;

   IF smthn = 2 THEN
     //make the query with different calculations//

    END//
        END IF;
```

Thanks

Comment: @StuartLC This is perfectly valid in MySQL, I suspect this is the variant of SQL he's using. `IF(BOOLEAN CONDITION, TRUE VALUE, FALSE VALUE)`

Comment: @StuartLC The brackets don't add up, looks like the comma is correct, but there's an extra closing bracket on the line for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF smthn = 1 THEN
    SELECT
        stuff,
        IFNULL(t3.value3,0.00) av_value,
        IF (t1.value1= t2.value2, t1.value1+ IFNULL(t3.value3,0.00) , t1.value1) kumul , -- Lose the extra closing bracket here.
        t2.value2 summa
FROM tbl_1 t1

-- You don't need END before your END IF
-- END//
END IF;

IF smthn = 2 THEN
    -- make the query with different calculations//

END IF;
```

Could you please try this variation of your code? I've commented the lines I've changed.

Comment: Yes, it was a syntax issue on my part and not nesting issue. Sorry about the trouble and thank you for correcting me!!

Answer (score -1):

**SQL Server** Syntax

```
IF smthn = 1 
BEGIN
 SELECT stuff ,
 ISNULL(t3.value3,0.00) av_value,
 case when (t1.value1= t2.value2 then t1.value1+ ISNULL(t3.value3,0.00) t1.value1) kumul ,)t2.value2 summa
FROM tbl_1 t1
END
ELSE IF smthn = 2
BEGIN
     --make the query with different calculations//
END
```